# How to set fixed caption at 3D plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a 3D plot and I need to place a text block on the top left of the screen, how can I implement this?

As i understand:

1. I can't place my own text at "key" block.
2. I can't place text with line-breaks at "title" block
3. "label" block is tied to the grid of the graph, not the screen.

I use the Windows terminal to rotate the graph in real time and it is important for me that this block of text remain in one place, that is, in the upper left part of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can. Check `help key`. `set key title "Text with\nlinebreak"`
2. you can. use `\n`, e.g. `set title "Some text\nwith\nlinebreaks"`
3. can also be tied to screen: `set label 1 "More\ntext" at screen 0.1, screen 0.8` check `help coordinates`

Answer (score 1):

\3. Starting with version 5.2, the command "set key fixed" will pin the key block to a fixed location on the screen independent of 3D plot rotation.

\2. See previous answer.

\1. Although gnuplot provides limited options for changing the layout of the auto-generated key block, you can create your own key block by specifying a specific location for each plot title.  This permits you to intersperse other text generated by "set label" commands if you like.  This is particularly useful for multiplots but it also works for individual plots.  Here is a fragment extracted from an example in the online demo set.

```
set label 1 at screen 0.75, screen 0.22 "{/:Bold Custom combined key area}" center
set key autotitle columnhead nobox title "  "
set multiplot layout 3,2 columnsfirst \
              title "{/:Bold Illustrate use of a custom key area}" \
              margins 0.05, 0.95, 0.05, 0.90 spacing 0.0, 0.0

plot 'immigration.dat' using 0:6   lt 1 title at 0.75, 0.18
plot 'immigration.dat' using 0:12  lt 2 title at 0.75, 0.15
plot 'immigration.dat' using 0:13  lt 3 title at 0.75, 0.12
plot 'immigration.dat' using 0:14  lt 4 title at 0.75, 0.09
set xtics scale 0 font ",8"

plot 'immigration.dat' using 0:($6+$12+$13+$14):xtic(strcol(1)[6:]) with linespoints lt black pt 7 title "total"

unset multi
```

[image]